# boolean not working correctly with http get result

Tags: java

```
public class networking2{

public static void main(String []args) throws IOException{
    String urlLink = "http://rocktheparty5231.xtgem.com/out";
    URL url = new URL(urlLink);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    String line;
    while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {sb.append(line);}
    in.close();

    // problem is here
    System.out.println(sb.toString()); // sb is returning output "uc"
    System.out.println(sb.toString()=="uc"); // how is this boolean false
    // i am not able to do any boolean operation with this correctly please help

}
```

}

**http functions are working perfectly but the boolean is not working as it should work**

[image: screenshot of eclipse]

Comment: Required reading for you: ['==' vs 'equals()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-and-equals-in-java#7520464). In short, == checks in-memory reference, equals() (generally) checks value.

Comment: thank you for the knowledge now i understand why it was false

Answer (score 3):

In Java, when comparing string, use `.equals`. Please have a try like this.

```
System.out.println(sb.toString().equals("uc"));
```

You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/string-equals-versus)

Comment: omg this works like magic my problem is solved within 2 min i was struggling from whole day thank you so much you are awesome

Comment: with my pleasure